# What's the size (diameter) of default radio button?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

Well, amazingly I could not find the answer neither in Google nor hear.

Some html/css expert can tell us?

Comment: It depends on the browser, the OS, the device and sometimes on the user's personal settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is probably that there is not a default size. Different browsers render them differently, which is the case for a lot of things in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

My developer tools tell me it is around 12~13px in diameter.

Regards **tschaefermedia**

Answer (score 0):

Well size of a radio button is not fixed is totally depends upon your device.

But you can customize it according to you need also by using `:before` or `:after` property of css.